# An alternative way to test primality of Fermat numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove following statement :

> Let's define an infinite sequence of positive integers :
>
> $ a_i=\cos(4^{i} \cdot \arccos(4)) ; i=1,2,3......$
>
> then for $n \geq 2 , F_n$ is prime if and only if :
>
> $a_{2^{n-1}-1} \equiv 0 \pmod {F_n}$

For example :

$ a_1 \equiv 0 \pmod {F_2}$

$ a_3 \equiv 0 \pmod {F_3}$

$ a_7 \equiv 0 \pmod {F_4}$

Comment: cosine has range [-1, 1].  So, $a_i$ is between -1 and 1 always.  Why are you looking at $a_i$ mod $F_n$?  If it's congruent to 0, it IS 0.

Comment: @Graphth,try to compute $\cos(4^1 \cdot \arccos(4))$ for example...